# Joining Tables: Only (!) add missing rows

Tags: sql, database, hana

I want to join the following tables (`records`, `tip`). Goal is that the missing `WAR` rows (dependend on the `ID`) will be added. For example you see that `WAR = 2` is missing for `ID = 80`.

Note: `WAR` is always smaller or equal with the value of TIP. The value of `Value` should be `NULL` in the added rows. The table in the bottom is the goal.

[image]

I am not sure how to solve this problem. But a condition that results of this is `records."TIP" >= tip."TIP"`.

I use HANA as database.

Thank you in advance. Best regards.

Comment: I'm not familiar with hana, but you can: select ditinct ID,max(tip), join TIP on 1=1 where tip<max(tip), Left outer join records and with case when complete the nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it works (sorry all these TIPs are a little bit confusing):

```
   SELECT a."ID", b."TiP" "WAR", c."VAL" FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT "ID", MAX("TIP") "max" FROM records t
        GROUP BY "ID"
    ) a
    INNER JOIN tip b ON 1=1
    LEFT JOIN T0 c ON a."ID" = c."ID" AND b."TiP" = c."WAR"
    WHERE b."TiP" <= a."max"
    ORDER BY a."ID", b."TiP"
```